# Ib mathematics HL IA exploration

Tags: calculus

For my mathematics HL class i decided to do my IA upon squaring the circle, but i have no idea what i can create or apply from this question. What i have done so far is explanied why it is jmpossble to do and demonstrated the math behind it. Furthermore i solved the problem myself through the use of calculus (integration). Now from apart of this i do not know how to continue my IA, i was thinking perhaps creating or turning the problem 3D, and take the surface área of a cube and set it equivlent to that of a sphere (this sounds relativily easy, but im not sure). BUT  I WAS wondering if anyone else has any other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I completed the IB Math HL IA in 2014. Based on my experience, a topic solely focusing on a single geometric problem will not earn good scores. However, there are definitely ways to improve on it. Some ideas may be to:

- Consider more about the fundamentals about "squaring the circle". What does it show regarding rational and irrational numbers?
- Think of applications regarding having different shapes with equal areas. How can this knowledge be applied?
- A 3D extension of the problem would be interesting - as would a n-dimensional problem. How would a n-dimensional problem look like? Perhaps set up the system for not just circles and squares, but for other regular polyhedra?
- A particularly interesting aspect will be to explore calculating volumes for high dimension polyhedra, and trying to compare volumes. Perhaps consider why there are only 6 Platonic Solids, and what that may mean?

I would advise speaking with your Math HL teacher about this further to see how to proceed. Best of luck!